# Does the exception report ever change, say after the project board has review it

Tags: prince2

The issue report template has fields to be filled after the change has been made, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that for the exception report, except for lessons learnt, so is the exception report only filled out once, and that's it, it's done and dusted forever, or is it ever updated.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for the official Prince2 answer, as opposed to a general project best practice. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep.That's correct

Comment: Okay, just want to make sure. Not a Prince2 person so didn't want to give a generic answer if you were looking for "the one" answer. PMBOK is the same way.

Answer (score 2):

From [PRINCE2 Plans - Levels, Types and Scope](http://www.projectinabox.org.uk/article7.asp):

> **Exception Plans**
>   An Exception Plan is required whenever part of the project is predicted to go outside its tolerances. People encountering the concept of Exception Plan for the first time sometimes think that it's a different type of plan from a Project or Stage Plan. In fact it's just a potential replacement for the plan that covers that part of the project that is in exception. So if a Stage is going to exceed its tolerances, your Exception Plan will replace the Stage Plan and be of the same design. It's intended to cover a different time period however: from "now" to the end of the original planning period.
>
> Technically, you could simply replace the existing plan with the appropriate Exception Plan but don't forget that you need the approval of the Project Board to replace a Stage Plan and the approval of wider corporate management to replace a Project Plan.

So it seems that the Exception Report needs to be updated (and escalated) whenever new data about slippage is discovered.